# PhP file_exists returns false when attempting to acess a file on local network server

Tags: php, iis-8, windows-server-2012, file-exists

Hello i am running multiple servers on a local network. One of these servers is hosting my web server IIS. I am trying to acess a file located on another server via php. I checked on the server if by using windows explorer if i could reach the file and i could but php returns false.

On my computer which is also connected to the same network running wamp i was able to read the file on the server.

Does anyone have any ideas why i am having this issue ?

My php code is the following :

```
$dbName = "\\\\server\\db_folder\\db.accdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
else {
    // i read my access db which works on wamp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use forward slash..

$dbName = "/server/db_folder/db.accdb";

Comment: Sorry this does not work as the server is trying to reach a file on another server on the same network. My dbName variable is escaping backslahes so the actual link is "\\server\db_folder\db.accdb". This works on my wamp installation on my computer.